# Abbreviated type name long long vs long long int, is it standard-compliant?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, language-lawyer

Most of the code I see use abbreviated types to declare a variable, such as

```
long long x; // long long int x
short y; // short int y
```

I skimmed through the C++11 standard (Sec. `3.9.1`) and the type is always declared fully, as `long long int`. I couldn't find any mentioning of abbreviated types. I am pretty sure the abbreviations are standard-compliant, but wanted to make sure if this is indeed the case. So my question is whether the above code is fully standard compliant.

Comment: When I need an exact type I prefer, by far, using types like int16_t or int32_t as defined in stdint.h

Comment: @Antonio But when do you need an exact type?

Comment: @JamesKanze Image processing, for example.

Comment: @Antonio Why would you need an exact type for image processing?

Comment: @JamesKanze It all starts from (let's say grayscale) pixels, which usually have an exact type (8 bit unsigned). Then, for examples, you convolve with a mask, and you know your result will have a certain size (e.g. 16 bit signed). You have to store the result in memory, the exact type is the best option. Also, it's very convenient when starting using SSE/NEON instruction set.

Comment: @Antonio I think your argument is more for fixed sized types when using shared memory with a co-processor or a display device.  I can accept that; both your code and the co-processor must see the same size.  (Although the fixed size types probably aren't necessary, since the code won't be portable anyway.)  But the actual image processing I've seen (trying to find specific patterns in the image) had no need of fixed width sizes.

Comment: @JamesKanze If you want to be kind and say that somehow I might be right, I appreciate that. :) But I actually meant exactly what I wrote, and finding patterns in general enjoys using exact types because they allow more efficiency, both in use of memory and in parallel processing of multiple pixels.

Comment: @Antonio Using precise types doesn't allow as much efficiency, and it definitely reduces portability.  With regards to memory usage, `std::int_least_8` might be appropriate, although in practice, this will always be a typedef to `char`.  With regards to the actual operations, of course, integral promotion means that the generated code is using at least `int` anyway; introducing a lot of other types just confuses the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is valid it is covered in the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `7.1.6.2` *Simple type specifiers* which says:

> Table 10 summarizes
>   the valid combinations of simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify.

and in Table `10` *simple-type-specifiers and the types they specify* says:

```
long long      “long long int”
```

and:

```
short          “short int”
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. But, since, C++99 it's far better to use the sized types

```
std::int8_t
std::int16_t
std::int32_t
std::int64_t
```

and their unsigned cousins `std::uint8_t` *etc* whenever possible. Then you know what you're dealing with.

Note that compilers don't have to support the 64 bit integral types.

Comment: They don't have to support the 32 bit, 16 bit or 8 bit integral types either. In fact, they don't have to support *any* `intN_t` typedef. This is pretty much an academic problem, unless you're on a really weird (e.g. 9-bit byte, or 48-bit integer without subsets) architecture, but it's not just ancient mainframes: some modern DSPs work this way.

Comment: It's only better to use the fixed-size-types **if you need them**. At least use the least-size-types if you can: `int_least8_t` `int_least16_t` ...

Comment: Unfortunately, sized types have traps of their own.  Given `uint32_t x=0xFF000000;`, the statement `x=x*x;` will work as expected if `int` is 32 bits but revoke the laws of time, space, and causality if `int` is 64 bits.  Worse that that, some people seem to think compilers *should* revoke the laws of time, space, and causality in the latter case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see table 10 in 7.1.6.2, which defines the mapping from various specifier combinations to the types from 3.9.